# "Requested unknown parameter" datatables error passing data from PHP to JS

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add an extra default columns (edit and remove button), and the rest of rows, dinamics.

I get this error when I try to pass my `$resultados` and I get it with `datos` in my JS code.

```
DataTables warning: table id=tablaUsuarios - Requested unknown parameter 'ACCIÓN' for row 0, column 6. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

My `$resultados` already contains the data correctly (even with the extra column):

[image]

And I see my table with my data but not with the buttons column (and I have this data inside of `$resultados` variable, as you can see in the previous screenshoot).

[image]

This is my full code:

```
<?php

include_once(DIR_PLUGINS.'/alexcrudgenerator/main.php');

    $test = new GenerateCrud($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);

    switch($_POST['action']){
        
        case 'datosTabla': // OK.
            
            $res = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
            echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            
            break;
            
        case 'showtable': // OK.

            $res = getEntireTable($_POST['tableName'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['tableFields']);
            
            foreach ($res as $data){
                
                $data->botones = "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button id='modificar_$data->id' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar' value='edit'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button onclick='Delete($data->id)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='material-icons' value='delete'>delete</i></button></div></div>"; 
                $resultados['data'][] = $data;
            }           
            
            $resultados = json_encode($resultados); // 7 PROPIEDADES
            
            foreach(json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsDB){
                $fields[] = array('data'=>$columnsDB);
            }

            $fields[]['data'] = 'ACCIÓN';
            $fields = json_encode($fields);
            
?>
            <head>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            
            <div class="container caja">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div>
                            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed hover" style="width:100%" >
                                <thead class="text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach (json_decode($_POST['tableFields']) as $columnsTH){
                                                echo '<th>' . strtoupper($columnsTH) . '</th>';
                                            }
                                            echo '<th>ACCIÓN</th>';
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var datos= <?=$resultados?>;
                    var dynamicColumns = <?=$fields?>;
                    datos = JSON.stringify(datos); // I convert to JSON AGAIN because if not, my data is not showed

                    $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
                        "language": {"url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                        "paging": true,
                        "lengthChange": true,
                        "searching": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "autoWidth": true,
                        "scrollX": true,

                        "ajax":{
                            "url": '<?=SITE_URL_ADMIN?>/alexcrudgenerator/crud/res/',
                            "method": 'POST',
                            "data":{action: "datosTabla", datos: datos}
                        },

                        "columns": dynamicColumns
                    });
                })
            </script>
<?php
        break;      
}
?>
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey! may the accent on ACCIÓN do something wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to read your screenshot of the `$resultados` variable. This is one of the [reasons why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) it is almost always better to provide data as text, not as images of text.

Comment: Having said that, it looks as if your `$resultados` buttons data value is called `botones` - but you appear to be using the heading name here: `$fields[]['data'] = 'ACCIÓN';` instead of the data value name. So, what happens if you change that to `$fields[]['data'] = 'botones';`?

Comment: @DafuQi Thank you for your reply, unfortunatelly, no, the accent is not giving problems :D

Comment: @andrewjamesOhhh, yes, you are right ... I had to change `$fields[]['data'] = 'ACCIÓN';` to `$fields[]['data'] = 'botones';`. Thank you very much. You can reply my question and I will accept your answer! Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$resultados` buttons data value is called `botones` - but you appear to be using the heading name here: `$fields[]['data'] = 'ACCIÓN';` instead of the data value name.

You can change that to `$fields[]['data'] = 'botones';`, instead.